# Adding pages to WP Dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

What is the correct way to add new pages to the wordpress dashboard. Not like creating a dashboard page, but instead make arbitrary pages as needed for use in lightboxes, etc.

One example, I need to query the server to get an "email preview" for a plugin I am working on. How do I create a URL that will run that particular script?

I imagine the URL would be like /wp-admin/index.php?page=my_plugin_email_preview

What functions do I need to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least:

```
add_menu_page();
add_submenu_page();
```

Comment: The problem is I don't need a link to the page, I just want a URL. The intention is to use these for ajax or pull them in an iframe. Can these make a page without creating the navigation menus?

Comment: Yes, setting the menu title parameter to "". Check the functions in Codex. I don't know if there is something like and add_page() function that accomplish what you want. I haven't check that.

Comment: Is this still the way to do it in 2021?